# How do I prove the estimates?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Suppose that $u\in H^{1}(U)$ is the unique weak solution of the boundary value problem

$-\sum_{i,j=1}^n(a^{ij}u_{x_i})_{x_j}+2u=f$ in $U$

$u=g$ on $\partial U$, where $g$ be the trace on $\partial U$ of an $H^1(U)$ function $w$.

Prove that i) $\|u\|_{H^1{(U)}}\leq C(\|f\|_{L^2{(U)}}+\|w\|_{H^1{(U)}}$.

ii)$\|u\|_{H^2{(U)}}\leq C(\|f\|_{L^2{(U)}}+\|w\|_{H^2{(U)}}$, where $w,u \in {H^2{(U)}}$.

Can anyone suggest to me some hints for this question?

Comment: What is your background? Which textbook are you reading from/ course are you taking? All this is important to somebody who wants to answer the question but doesn't want to use things you don't know.

Comment: Are there assumptions on $a^{ij}$ that make this an elliptic problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to make some small additional assumptions.
We assume that the problem is elliptic (this requires assumptions on $a^{ij}$).
We fruther assume that $f\in L^2(U)$.

Then we can use the following arguments.
Let $L$ denote the differential operator on the left-hand side,
so that we currently have $Lu=f$ on $U$, $u=g$ on $\partial U$.
Using $w$, this is equivalent to
$$
L(u-w) = f- Lw\text{ in }U,\quad u-w=0\text{ on }\partial U.
$$
This is an elliptic PDE with zero boundary conditions,
and with the right-hand side $f-Lw\in H^{-1}(U)$.

Then one can apply standard estimates for elliptic PDEs,
which leads to
$$
\|{u-w}\|_{H^1(U)} \leq C\|{f-Lw}\|_{H^{-1}(U)}.
$$
Here, we can apply the triangle inequalities,
norm estimates for $L$, and embedding inequalities to obtain
$$
\|{u}\|\leq \|{w}\|+\|{u-w}\|
\leq \|{w}\|+C\|{f-Lw}\|_{H^{-1}(U)}
\leq (C\|{L}\|+1)\|{w}\|+C\|{f}\|_{H^{-1}(U)}
\leq (C\|{L}\|+1)\|{w}\|_{H^1(U)}+C^2\|{f}\|_{L^2(U)},
$$
where $C>0$ is a suitable constant.

Similar, one can obtain estimates for $H^2(U)$.
This time, we have $f-Lw\in L^2(U)$.
Using the standard estimates yields
$$
\|{u-w}\|_{H^2(U)} \leq C\|{f-Lw}\|_{L^2(U)}.
$$
This implies
$$
\|{u}\|_{H^2(U)}\leq \|{w}\|_{H^2(U)}+\|{u-w}\|_{H^2(U)}
\leq \|{w}\|_{H^2(U)}+C\|{f-Lw}\|_{L^2(U)}
\leq (C\|{L}\|+1)\|{w}\|_{H^2(U)}+C\|{f}\|_{L^2(U)}.
$$
Overall, I have used other constants than you.